# what does wavelet decomposition structure mean?

Tags: matlab, wavelet, decomposition, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

running the code:

```
>> load('matlabF.mat')
>> f

   f =

     4     6    10    12     8     6     5     5

>> [c,l] = wavedec(f,3,'haar');
>> c

    c =

    19.7990    2.8284   -6.0000    2.0000   -1.4142   -1.4142    1.4142         0

>> l

    l =

     1     1     2     4     8
```

can you please tell me what the elements in the arrays `c` and `l` mean?

Answer (score 2):

You gotta need to read [`matlabF`'s doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html) first.

`[C,L] = wavedec(X,N,'wname')` returns the wavelet decomposition of the signal `X` at level `N`, using `wname`. `N` must be a strictly positive integer (see `wmaxlev` for more information). The output decomposition structure contains **the wavelet decomposition vector `C`** and **the bookkeeping vector `L`**. The structure is organized as in this level-3 decomposition example.

[image]